# The ".replace" operator isn't working Python

Tags: python, string, pycharm, operators, modifier

I was testing some mechanics out and ran into an issue, the following program should replace the '+' sight to ' + '. The output of this theoretically should be '20 + 20', but in reality, it's '20+20'. I have no idea why.

```
string = "20+20"
if string.find(" ") == -1:
    string.replace("+", " + ")
print(string)
```

Comment: `replace` returns a new string.

Answer (score 2):

In order for this to work, you need to reassign the string variable with the result of string.replace as the replace function returns the new string.

```
string = "20+20"
if string.find(" ") == -1:
    string = string.replace("+", " + ")
print(string)
```